# Android Check how fast post request took

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to check how fast a Post request took to execute. I am doing the request inside an AsyncTask.

This is how I am currently checking for execution time

```
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            new POSTTask().execute();
            long end = System.nanoTime() - start;
```

I am not sure if the time given by this is the actual time it takes for the Post request. Inside the AsyncTask the only thing I am doing is the following

```
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

            List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", "tets1"));

            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);

            request.setEntity(formEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            Log.i("Result", result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Am I going about this the right way or the wrong way?

Comment: do you now what `async` implies, in `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not the actual time. You are trying to get execution time on main thread but your post query is running in a different thread in background.

Use it like this

```
try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", "tets1"));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);

        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        long end = System.nanoTime() - start;
        // Print value of end here
        result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        Log.i("Result", result);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, this works. Will mark right after 8 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is wrong.  The `execute` method on an `AsyncTask` returns immediately, before the request has been performed.

If you move the timing code into the `AsyncTask`, specifically by putting it around this line

```
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

you will get the actual time.

Answer (score 0):

that is wrong as those lines do not execute in order.

```
new POSTTask().execute();
```

starts a new thread meaning your 2 time stamps are going to be really close together like milliseconds apart and thats not accurate

what you should be doing all your timing in your `doInBackground`